# Creating Dictionaries from arrays in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 numpy arrays :

```
a = numpy.array([['x','y']])
b = numpy.array([['x1','y1']])
c = numpy.array([['x2','y2']])
```

I want to create a dictionary as:

```
d={'x': ['x1','x2'], 'y':['y1','y2']}
```

How do I create such a dictionary?

Comment: Don't you mean `d={'x':['x1','x2'],'y':['y1','y2']}` (`x2`, not `y1`)?

Comment: OP, please edit your question and fix the output or leave a comment clarifying if this is indeed the wanted output (which seems very unlikely).

Answer (score 3):

`zip` the arrays inside a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {x: list(*i) for x, i in zip(*a, (b, c))}
```

or, alternatively:

```
d = {x: [y, z] for x, (y, z) in zip(*a, (*b, *c))}
```

or, if you like deep unpacking scenarios:

```
d = {x: [y, z] for x, ((y, z),) in zip(*a, (b, c))}
```

there's quite a number of packing/unpacking combinations to choose from. All these of course produce the same output with the dictionary `d` now being:

```
{'x': ['x1', 'y1'], 'y': ['x2', 'y2']}
```

Comment: the OP's output *d={'x':['x1','y1'],'y':['y1','y2']}* (maybe a typo)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks for pointing that out. I err'ed in reading the output; pretty sure that's a typo but I'll wait and see.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want `d={'x':['x1','x2'],'y':['y1','y2']}` you can go:

```
d = {i: [j, x] for i,j,x in zip(a,b,c)}
```

Comment: You need to unpack `a`. This leads to a `TypeError` due to numpy arrays not being hashable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve your arrays:

```
print {k: a for k, a in zip(a[0], [b, c])}
>>> {'y': array([['x2', 'y2']], 
  dtype='|S2'), 'x': array([['x1', 'y1']], 
  dtype='|S2')}
```

Otherwise:

```
print {k: list(a[0]) for k, a in zip(a[0], [b, c])}
>>> {'y': ['x2', 'y2'], 'x': ['x1', 'y1']}
```

Comment: This is tagged with Python 3 so if you can update your answer to use print as a function. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `numpy` solution:

```
import numpy as np

dict(zip(np.ravel(a), np.vstack([b, c]).tolist()))

#{'x': ['x1', 'y1'], 'y': ['x2', 'y2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
d = {k:list(v) for k,v in zip(a,(b,c))}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'x': ['x1', 'y1'], 'y': ['x2', 'y2']}
```